# SEC EDGAR 20-F Form - How to process text that contains html tags

Tags: python, html, regex, edgar

I have the downloaded the following 20-F Form from SEC EDGAR:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1729089/000121390019021541/0001213900-19-021541.txt

As you can see, the .txt file contains multiple html tags such as:

```
</HEAD>
<BODY STYLE="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif">

<P STYLE="margin-top: 0; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0; font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif"></P>

<!-- Field: Rule-Page --><DIV STYLE="width: 100%"><DIV STYLE="font-size: 1pt; border-top: Black 2pt solid; border-bottom: Black 1pt solid">&nbsp;</DIV></DIV><!-- Field: /Rule-Page -->

<P STYLE="margin-top: 0; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0; font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif">&nbsp;</P>

<P STYLE="margin-top: 0; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0; font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif"><FONT STYLE="font-family: Times New Roman, Times, Serif; font-size: 10pt"><B>UNITED
STATES</B></FONT></P>

<P STYLE="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; text-align: center"><FONT STYLE="font-family: Times New Roman, Times, Serif; font-size: 10pt"><B>SECURITIES
AND EXCHANGE COMMISSION</B></FONT></P>

<P STYLE="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; text-align: center"><FONT STYLE="font-family: Times New Roman, Times, Serif; font-size: 10pt"><B>WASHINGTON,
D.C. 20549</B></FONT></P>

<P STYLE="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; text-align: center"><FONT STYLE="font-family: Times New Roman, Times, Serif; font-size: 10pt">&nbsp;</FONT></P>

<P STYLE="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; text-align: center"><FONT STYLE="font-family: Times New Roman, Times, Serif; font-size: 10pt"><B>FORM
20-F</B></FONT></P>
```

Since I want to perform Natural Language Processing (NLP) - Textual Analysis, do I need to get rid of all these HTML etc tags? How can I do that? Through regex or by using a package e.g. BeautifulSoup?